# Why is my 8-bit counter only counting until 127?

Tags: verilog, counter, modelsim, bit-rate, libero

I recently coded an 8-bit counter in Libero and simulated it in ModelSim using Verilog. When I simulated my design, it only went up to 127. Shouldn't an 8-bit counter go up to 255?

Here is my HDL Code:

```
module counter    (
out     ,  // Output of the counter
enable  ,  // enable for counter
clk     ,  // clock Input
reset      // reset Input
);

output [7:0] out;
 input enable, clk, reset;
 
reg [7:0] out;

always @(posedge clk)
if (reset) begin
out <= 8'b0 ;
end else if (enable) begin
out <= out + 1;
end
endmodule
```

Here is my Testbench Code:

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps

 module counter_tb;

 //parameter SYSCLK_PERIOD = 20;// 50MHZ

 reg clk_1;
 reg enable_1;
 reg reset_1;

 wire [7:0] out_1; 

 initial
 begin
 clk_1 = 1'b0;
 enable_1 = 1'b0;
 reset_1 = 1'b1;

 #20;

 enable_1 = 1'b1;
 reset_1 = 1'b0;

 #20;
 end

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Clock Driver
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 always
    #10 clk_1 = ~clk_1;


 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Instantiate Unit Under Test:  counter
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 counter counter_0 (
      // Inputs
     .enable(enable_1),
     .clk(clk_1),
     .reset(reset_1),

       // Outputs
       .out( out_1 )

        // Inouts

        );

  endmodule
```

Here is my simulation from ModelSim.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on your choice of datatypes. An 8 bit signed counter would stop at 127. But you haven't posted any useful information for looking any deeper.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Here is my code and simulation result.

Comment: @JRE I added my ModelSim and code.

Comment: If you interpret 128 as 8-bit signed, the value is -128.

Comment: @Justin I am not sure what you mean. Could you please explain?

Comment: You are displaying the value as a signed integer, you need as an unsigned or hex for example.

Comment: The circuit is working fine, the part that is confusing you is the display in the simulation waveform viewer when it shows -128, -127, -126... Those are actually the 2's complement representations. You could probably fix it by adding `unsigned` to either the `reg [7:0] out` or `output [7:0] out` (I'm not sure which).

Comment: @BrianDrummond, the problem isn’t in the Verilog, it’s in the waveform viewer.

Comment: @yer why are you saying that the counter only counts up to 127 when that is clearly not all that happens?

Comment: @ThePhoton Comment still applies : it's just that the datatype choice is made when displaying results instead of at the design stage, where IMO it would be more useful.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, Typical VHDL bondage & discipline thinking ;)

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes! I discipline my designs and they don't (usually :-) dare displease me with surprises like this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Modelsim waveform display, you need to right-click on the output signal and change the data representation to unsigned. It's currently interpreting the 8-bit value as a signed integer.